# What is the fastest way of exporting hundreds of thousands of rows on postgresql and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, csv, stream, export-to-csv

I've been working on exporting a complex SQL query that returns about 500.000 rows,

I had built a nice stream pipe line that streams data from postgresql -> converts into CSV -> publish into S3.

But I want it to be sync, and its being kind of a problem since its taking more then 10 minutes to finish everything.

Is there a way I can do that in, like, 1 minute? If not, what would be the fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL to CSV, the COPY statement is by far the fastest option. [pg-copy-streams](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-copy-streams) might help, but there are other options as well.

I can't help you with S3, no experience.

Comment: [pg-query-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-query-stream) is better for read-only requests, or you can use [pg-iterator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-iterator) to simplify usage.